# Convert a string to number without using any java conversion functions/utility classes

Tags: string, numbers, data-conversion

I was asked in a Java interview to write a program that would convert a string for example "123" into number 123 without using any of java's conversion functions/utility classes.

I am still confused if that would be possible. Any ideas ?
Thanks

Comment: what counts as a utility class? Could you have a map of strings to numbers, iterate over the string, look up the number by the string, and construct the number?

Answer (score 1):

Break the string into individual characters, map each to its numeric value, and combine by multiplying each by its place value.

Answer (score 0):

I should have made my comment an answer so I can get the answer credit :)

"what counts as a utility class? Could you have a map of strings to numbers, iterate over the string, look up the number by the string, and construct the number?"

in pseudocode:

```
Map<String, Integer> = {
"0":0,
"1":1,
"2":2,
... etc }

int number = 0;

for(i=string.length-1; i>=0; i--){
String substr = string.substring(i, i+1);
int digit = map.get(substr);
number += 10^(string.length-i)*digit;
}

return number
```

Comment: Colleen as per your supplied code, I wrote following:
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
map.put("0", 0);
map.put("1", 1);
map.put("2", 2);
map.put("3", 3);
map.put("4", 4);
map.put("5", 5);
map.put("6", 6);
map.put("7", 7);
map.put("8", 8);
map.put("9", 9);  

int number = 0;

String myNumber = "456";

for(int i=0; i < myNumber.length() - 1; i++) {
  String substr = myNumber.substring(i, i+1);
  int digit = map.get(substr);
  number += 10 ^ i * digit;
}
   
System.out.println(number);

Output: 25

This seems to be incorrect. Can you plz tell where I am wrong. Thanks

Comment: Also "map" is a complex Java object and I guess it might involve some automatic conversion when we use map.get() function. 
I wonder if the interviewer was concerned getting it some simpler way.

Comment: You're going to need to convert from Integer to int (I didn't because it was pseudocode). So it should work if you do int digit = (int) map.get(substr)

Comment: Also, the calculation for digit was off and I forgot that substring is inclusive, exclusive. Sorry about that! I edited the code to reflect these changes.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do it any simpler, though. Except maybe like 2 arrays that essentially act as a map?

Comment: Colleen I guess your very last comment using two arrays might be an option i.e using a simpler way rather than using complex object like map. Anyways thanks for helping out.